# Conflict between ajax and bootstrap in paginator of cakephp framwork

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cakephp, paginator

I coded a page about office. I have a controller "Congvanden". I want to use bootstrap, ajax and paginator in cakephp. But when I use `var $layout = false` in CongvandenController, the Paginator deactivetes. If I disable `var $layout = false`. the Paginator is perfect.

The prolem is the conflict layout in cakephp.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use a layout, then your are not importing any css nor js file. So you have to make your view a full html file, with head tag and body tag and all your script import. A better approach would be to have different layouts instead. Just create another layour with everything you need in the same folder where is the deaulft.ctp layout, let's say `myLayout.ctp` and in your controller change

```
var $layout = false;
```

for

```
var $layout = 'myLayout';
```

Also, make sure that the layour delcaration is in the action and not outside so it affects only a single view